# DotNetNuke stops working

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Several times during the day my DNN app stops working at random times. The server it runs on is not overloaded. DNN have been updated from v7.
Event logger says (I tried to translate it from Russian, sorry): **Timeout expired before the connection from the pool is available, perhaps all the connections are used and max pool amount achieved**. Stacktraces are different everytime but the following is common:

```
 в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   в PetaPoco.Database.OpenSharedConnection()
   в DotNetNuke.Data.PetaPoco.PetaPocoExt.ExecuteReader(Database database, String sql, Object[] args)
   в DotNetNuke.Data.PetaPoco.PetaPocoHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, CommandType type, String sql, Object[] args)
```

Does it suggest my SQL Server doesn't cope? But the other DNN apps (also old and updated) work just fine on the same server (both DNNs and SQL Server 2012 run on the same machine). What can be wrong with this exact DNN app?

Comment: Are you leaving your connections open in your application?

Comment: By `app` you mean the DNN CMS as a whole or a custom module?

Comment: That error does not mean SQL Server doesn't cope. It means that .NET connection pool has reached max number of connections, which in turn means you have too much connections open at the same time. Most often this is caused by not closing connections properly or running many long-running queries. You can increase max number of connections in pool, but in case you are leaving your connections open - that won't solve the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech I suppose I don't. The similar apps (DNN CMS @VDWWD) works fine. Moreover if the app fails I restart the IIS app, and DNN may fail again within a minute

Comment: @Evk As I said before DNN may fail right after when it has been restarted. Where can the long-running queries appear from so soon? (There is no load on this DNN app at all - just a couple of develores) And I don't quite understand what does it menas to close connections properly. Could you give an example please?

Comment: It means close when you dont need them any more. Either use "using" block or explicitly call Close on connection. Since you have this problem - ensure that you do not forget to close them.

Comment: @Evk DNN uses PetaPoco. And in my code I don't use low-level ADO.NET  API. So I don't think it's open connections...

Comment: Well I have no idea about DNN. But, the fact it uses some ORM does not mean you cannot forget to close a connection. For example in PetaPoco you have to Dipose your Database instance (or call CloseSharedConnection on it). This is not related to low level ADO.NET APIs.